# Running debugger but only from a certain point in the code

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

for context I'm using JetBrain's Pycharm's debugger for my code in python.
When running the code the debugger slows down the run time by quite a lot but I'm only interested in debugging values at the end.

Is there any way to run the debugger but only from a certain point in the code?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at `pdb.set_trace()`.

Comment: You can use Remote Debug Server for this, it can be run locally as well https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-debugging-with-product.html#remote-debug-config